# cant seem to get avg() to work with case in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

I want to use the average() with case, however my command below seems to be giving me an error but I cant figure why

```
SELECT 
avg(case when price between 0 AND 9 then price end),
avg(case when price between 10 AND 19 then price end),
avg(case when price between 20 AND 29 then price end),
avg(case when price between 30 AND 39 then price end),
avg(case when price between 40 AND 49 then price end)
FROM products;
```

The data base looks something like this:

```
ProductID   ProductName                    Price
1           Chais                           18 
2           Chang                           19 
3           Aniseed Syrup                   33
8           Northwoods Cranberry Sauce      40 
9           Mishi Kobe Niku                 97
```

Comment: Don't be shy.  Include the error in your question.  Also, tag your question with the database you are actually using.  SQL Server?  Or, SQLite?

Comment: The query you presented looks fine to me, and it runs without error for me in the databases you tagged (SQL Server and SQLite), and also in recent versions of MySQL, Oracle, and PostgreSQL.  In every case it returns value `34` for the average, which is correct for the given data and query.  If you are getting an error, then it seems unlikely to be related to the query and data you have presented.

Comment: You still have not told us what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
select avg (price) from products where price > 30
```

Comment: Not the same.  The average of 40 and 10 would be 40 not 20.

Comment: that is the average of the prices that are more than 30, so 40 is correct; if you need just average of all items, remove the where clause.

Comment: Average of items > 30 is not the stated question. avg(case when price > 30 then price else 0 end)

Comment: @Blam, you're quite right that the average of items > 30 is not the *stated* question, but it may nevertheless be the desired result.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. I needed more than one column thats why I didnt use the WHERE CLAUSE. I re-edited the question. Thanks

Comment: @GucciProgrammer That edit is a different question.

Comment: How? The title says cant get avg() to work with case which is what I was going for and what the edit describe

Comment: @GucciProgrammer One column row with a then 0 is different.  On hold.